# How to create site search feature in address bar of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, site-search

When you go to stackoverflow.com in Google Chrome and if you put a space infront of last character, the address bar changes to that in my screen shot below.

Then you can press Tab and you can type anything, and pressing enter will take you to the search page with your search term:  `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=anything`.

How can I do same thing for my site?

[image]

Comment: I'd assume that they already have site search set up and they just want to configure Chrome the way that StackOverflow does.  If that is the case, it is a very answerable question, not too broad at all.

Comment: It looks like somebody on the Google product forums figured this out: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/8EFOmC6pNLs/mGLVTtvtFgAJ

Comment: Damith, do you wish to add a site search **from the address bar**, or just a site search with autocomplete?

Comment: I'm too lazy at the moment to write a good answer, so here are two links: http://www.opensearch.org/Documentation/Frequently_asked_questions and for implementing this see: http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#OpenSearch_description_document

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I reread the question. My bad! I had in mind implementing a site search and somehow missed the true nature of the question. This is a good question. Cheers!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have a search feature on your site then you can take advantage of the **OpenSearch** functionality in Chrome.

Taken from the [Chromium documentation](https://www.chromium.org/tab-to-search):

To enable this for all users (even those who haven't used your search form):

On your site's homepage provide a link to an OpenSearch description document. The link to the OSDD is placed in the head of the html file. For example:

```
<head>
  <link type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"
        rel="search"
        href="url_of_osdd_file"/>
</head>
```

The important part of this document is the URL used to search your site.

The following is an example that contains the bare minimum needed, see the OpenSearch description document specification for the list of values you can specify.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <ShortName>Search My Site</ShortName>
  <Description>Search My Site</Description>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get"
       template="http://my_site/{searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

When the user presses enter in the Omnibox the string {searchTerms} in the url is replaced with the string the user typed.

You can also include a suggestion service by adding another URL element with `rel="suggestions"` such as:

```
<Url type="application/json"
     rel="suggestions"
     template="http://my_site/suggest?q={searchTerms}"
     />
```

If you include this, the omnibox will use your suggestion service to provide query suggestions based on the user's partial query.

If your search box uses a GET request, then Chrome will enable this feature for uses who use it.

If you don't have a search page on your site then this won't work.

Props to Stephen for the initial link.